# WCF - Error Handling

Tags: wcf, error-handling

I have my WCF Service hosted in Windows Service. The client application is a website project to which I added the Service reference.

I was not using any error logging/tracing... but now I feel I should implement as it will help me not to make void guesses.

Please guide me for the best practice so that I can quickly handle errors and pin point the exact issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to see the error message for troubleshooting purposes, you can set [IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx) attribute in your app.config. This will give you the full exception details, including a stack trace on your client. However, be aware that exception details may include sensitive information, so don't leave it on in a production system without understanding the risk.

If you want to take it a step further, you can implement the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface. You can use this as a single point of logging exceptions or translating them into published Fault Contracts.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to maintaining a more robust WCF Service is logging all operations made.

[The Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139916.aspx) works for me. you might also want to check log4net.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for general information on debugging WCF services, I recommend reading the following articles:

[Debugging WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514135.aspx)

[Configuring Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)

[Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

[Debugging WCF Services in Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2008/03/17/debugging-wcf-services-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)